# JavaScript: Is there a regular expression library that fully supports lookarounds?

Tags: javascript, regex

As [JavaScript’s built-in regular expression library](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) does not support [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind), I wondered if there’s a library that implements a regular expression engine purely in JavaScript.

In my case, the performance does not matter (as long as searching for simple expressions in short strings does not take seconds or longer).

Comment: I've changed my code, now it parses the input strings and so it's no longer necessary to use RegExp lookarounds. Too bad it doesn't work, Regular Expression had reduced the code complexity.

Answer (score 1):

A common workaround for the lack of look-behind is to match (rather than anchor to) what comes before the bit you're interested in, then reinsert it in the callback.

To replace all instances of `foo` with `bar`, where it is preceded by a number.

```
var str = 'foo 1foo foo2';
console.log(str.replace(/(\d)foo/g, function($0, $1) {
    return $1+'bar';
})); //foo 1bar foo1
```

There *are* implementations of lookbehind in JS, **including one I wrote ([docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20130403012523js_/http://mitya.co.uk/scripts/source/164.js); [code](https://web.archive.org/web/20130403012523js_/http://mitya.co.uk/scripts/source/164.js))**, where a positive or negative lookbehind is passed as an extra parameter. Using that, this would get the same result as the above:

```
console.log(str.replace2(/foo/g, 'bar', '(?<=\\d)'));
```

Comment: As commented on KooiInc's answer, these workarounds do not suffice for complex regular expressions.

Comment: The OP did not ask solely about complex REGEX. For most REGEXP patterns, they will probably work, but there is no getting around the fact that, ultimately, JS doesn't support look-behinds natively.

Comment: "including one I wrote" link is down, please update it

Comment: @Utkanos "There are implementations of lookbehind in JS". Besides yours and Xregx do you know any other advanced regex lib for js ?