# Alternatives to (?<=exp) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I read some tutorials about regex and I saw a sentence:

> (?<=exp): Match any position following a prefix exp

For example, I have some strings:

> Share
>
> Care

If I want to find all string include "are", but "are" must follow "Sh": `/(?<=Sh)are/i`. Now only "Share" is matched, and matched index is 2 (match "are", not "Share" from "Share").

But Javascript don't have this regex. How can I do like that in Javascript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it. There are no lookbehind assertions in Javascript's implementation of regular expressions.

**Alternatives**

- In some situations you can instead use a grouping to capture what you actually wanted to match: `/Sh(are)/i`
- If you really need lookbehinds you could use a third-party regular expression library.

**Related**

- [JavaScript: Is there a regular expression library that fully supports lookarounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702735/javascript-is-there-a-regular-expression-library-that-fully-supports-lookaround)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to matched index is 2 (match "are"): "Share".search(regex) = 2. Any idea for me?

Comment: @BoodCarley: You could use a third-party regular expression library. See my update for a link to a similar question.

Answer (score 2):

The only way (and of course this only works if you don't also have a lookahead assertion in your regex) is to reverse the string and use a lookahead instead of lookbehind:

```
/era(?=hS)/i
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [non capturing groups](http://javascript.about.com/library/blre16.htm)

```
/(?:sh)(are)/
```

this tells the regex to find `are` without capturing the `sh` group. However in this context, as you have a simple pattern to match, this is not necessary and you can find the answer in other solutions and do something like

```
/sh(are)/
```

matching then only the first group

Comment: `'Share Care'.match(/(?=.+?are)(.+?)/)` returns `["S", "S"]` - test much?

Comment: Thanks, but it's not which I want.

Answer (score 0):

If I well understood I would use this regexp

```
/(Sh|\b)(are)/gi
```

where `are` can be only a single word or a substring preceded by `Sh`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if I use this regex, matched index is 0, not 2. Can you give me more solutions?

Comment: Why the index should matter? what string are you trying to match? Please provide a fiddle

Comment: For highlighting result, for example. I want to find "are" satisfy some conditions.